# Regex - ignoring quotes

Tags: regex

I'm using the regex

```
(?:^|;)\s*([^=]*[^=\s])\s*=\s*([^;]*[^;\s])
```

on the following string

```
"""A"" = .B; ""C"" = .D; ""E"" = .F"
```

The second capture group `([^;]*[^;\s])` matches the text `.B`, `.D` and `.F"`, whilst the first capture group matches the text `"""A""`, `"C""` and `""E""`.

How can I update this regex to match the text only, i.e., `.B`, `.D` and `.F`, and `A`, `C` and `E`?

I've tried add the quoted to the capture groups, e.g., `([^=\"]*[^=\s])`, but this seems to have no affect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match zero or more quotes before the key value and then restrict the `[^=\s]` character class to avoid matching `"` by adding it to the class and again match 0+ quotes right after:

```
(?:^|;)\s*"*([^=]*[^=\s"])"*\s*=\s*([^;]*[^;\s"])
          ^^           ^  ^^                  ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WFHxLc/1). Note that `[^;]*` will also match double quotes if any since it is a greedy pattern.

**Details**

- `(?:^|;)` - start of string or `;`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"*` - 0+ double quotes
- `([^=]*[^=\s"])` - Group 1:

  - `[^=]*` - 0+ chars other than `=`
  - `[^=\s"]` - a char other than `=`, whitespace and `"`
- `"*` - 0+ double quotes
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `([^;]*[^;\s"])` - Group 2:

  - `[^;]*` - 0+ chars other than `;`
  - `[^;\s"]` - a char other than `;`, whitespace and `"`.

[image]